# Is there a way to apply the pixellate filter on a vignette filter using the GPUImage library?

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage

I am trying to achieve an effect that includes a GPUImage vignette filter + a pixelate filter as well, but it looks like the vignette is not pixellated.

Probably the reason is why it doesn't pixellate the vignette, because the vignette filter is not a blend filter.

Apart from the short answer - "no, it's no possible", do you know any workaround how to achieve this effect?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is possible :)

**Option 1**: try filter groups with both filters. You can find the docs for the Filter Groups on Github page of GPUImage lib.

**Option 2**: if you are processing image, apply vignette filter to the image, get the result 
image, apply pixellate filter to the result image.

Hope this helps.